# Can DVD-R disks be used to create a boot disk?(linux iso)

Tags: linux, dvd, iso-image, bootable-media, burning

Can DVD-R disks be used to create a boot disk?(linux iso). I am trying to install linux on my imac powerpc g5 which wont boot from a bootable usb.

Answer (score 2):

Any type of DVDs that have enough size can be used for that.

Answer (score 2):

As Manoj Sawai Said **Yes.**

But you may need an external Dvd Drive.

Please read the Note at the bottom. For issues reading Newly burned Discs.

You Burn the image on to the disc.

Do the same as you would with the usb Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>C</kbd> and wait for the menu to come up and show the disc then boot the live cd and install it from there.

Shouldnt have any further issues after that.

**Note:** ive read that it may not read the burned DVD to well you may need to buy a portable Dvd drive and install it from that. [Read here for more info on that.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1144393?start=45&tstart=0)